# why this class is giving me an unkown error C#?

Tags: c#

```
 public class Nodes
    {
        private Nodes nodeOne;
        private Nodes nodeTwo;
        private NodeType type;
        private string extraInfo;

        public Nodes(NodeType type, string info)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.extraInfo = info;
        }



        public Nodes node_One
        {
            get { return this.nodeOne; }
            set { this.nodeOne = value; }
        }
        public Nodes node_Two
        {
            get { return this.node_Two; }
            set { this.nodeTwo = value; }
        }
        public NodeType nodeType
        {
            get { return this.type; }
            set { this.type = value; }

        }
        public string extraInf
        {
            get { return this.extraInfo; }
            set { this.extraInfo = value; }
        }


    }

     enum NodeType
    {
        AND,
        OR,
        PROPOSITION,
    }
```

and I use it here:

```
    if (dsPubs.Tables["Diccionario"].Rows.Contains(cmATomic.SelectedItem)) 
        {
         aux = new Nodes(NodeType.PROPOSITION, cmATomic.SelectedText);
         nodeList.Add(aux); 
        }
```

so, every time i try to make an object an insert it in a list of nodes, it does , but when I put a break point in the list just to figure out what is storing  in each position on the list , it gives me an weird mistake and the program suddenly end without not giving any kind of exception. 
 when i hover the mouse over the List just to see the collection it apperas somtheing like this

```
 [?]
 [?]
 [?]
 [?]
```

and the program ends.

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite recursion here:

```
public Nodes node_Two
{
    get { return this.node_Two; }
```

Any attempt to read the property `node_Two` will result in a stack overflow exception.  Not just in your program but in Visual Studio itself.

You probably meant this:

```
public Nodes node_Two
{
    get { return this.nodeTwo; } // <-- use the variable, not the property
```

Note that consistent and sensible variable naming can help a lot to prevent mistakes like this.

Comment: If this is the actual code for these, then `public Nodes node_Two { get; set; }` is simpler and less error prone (auto property).

Comment: I fully agree with your comment on naming. This code was very hard to read even though it's an extremely simple class.